# Alter Nginx.conf file to route to rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

Okay, this is my first ever vps, and this is my hello world test. I'm one step away from displaying my rails application

I have a VPS running Ubuntu.

I have a rails project just sitting here:

(I pulled it from git hub using git, and ran 'bundle install' to install the gems on the vps, haven't used Capistrano at all)

> *root* /home/starkers/rails_application ->
>
> test_app

When I visit my vps' ip in a browser I recieve the `Welcome to nginx!` page.

Finally,

```
sudo nano /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

Opens my config file.

Now, I haven't made any headway on this in about an hour. All the online guides show a slightly different nginx.conf structure so I'm a little bit in the dark here.

The nginx.conf file is pretty large, what variables do I need to change in order to make a direct http request to the server route to the rails project?

I think this is what matters for my purposes:

```
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;
 #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
   }
```

I'd be most grateful if someone could explin this to me a bit more. I'm betting the index.html referenced here is the "Welcome to nginx!" page. Should a public webserver always listen on port 80? Does the server_name matter?

How can I then tweak the nginx.conf file so that a url I purchased will route the project?

Really wouldn't mind some help here.

Comment: Do you plan on hosting more than one website from this vps? If not, you can add the domain name you'll be using to the `server_name` above. Also, did you have an app server in mind? I'd recommend the [passenger gem](http://modrails.com).

Answer (score 0):

This is really a multi-step process. You will need to:

1. Configure a nginx server block for the domain you want to host your app from.
2. Configure an application server or other "bridge" between your rails app and nginx. I'd recommend the passenger gem.

If you decide to go the passenger route, you could modify the server block above similar to the following:

```
passenger_root /somewhere/passenger-x.x.x;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
passenger_max_pool_size 10;
server {
    # uncomment the line below if you will be serving multiple domains/websites from this box
    # server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;

    # point this to the path to your rails app's public directory
    root /home/starkers/rails_application/test_app/public;

    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

Source: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html

This [HOW TO install guide from digitalocean may be of interest to you](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu).